# Obtaining the ISO 8601 date format, e.g.: 2009-06-15T13:45:30

Tags: java, c#, date, datetime

How do you format your date in ISO 8601? E.g.: `2009-06-15T13:45:30`

Is there a standard way of generating it from Java without having to create a `DateTimeFormatter` with a letter pattern?

I see it used in MS documentation:
[Standard Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Comment: This is ISO 8601 format and you can format string like that using "s" (sortable) format specifier (in C#).

Comment: @Evk It's *almost* ISO 8601 format - the timezone identifier is missing.

Comment: @1615903 When I read those wiki pages correctly, the timezone information is **not** mandatory. When left out, it means "local time"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy ways to obtain ISO 8601 in Java:

```
static void time() {
    final DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME;
    OffsetDateTime.now().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS).format(fmt);
    Instant.now().atOffset(ZoneOffset.ofHours(1)).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS).format(fmt);
    Instant.now().atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS).format(fmt);
    OffsetDateTime.parse("2007-12-03T10:15:30+01:00").format(fmt);
    LocalDateTime.parse("2009-06-15T13:45:30").format(fmt);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this is the commonly referred to as "ISO" date.

Documented in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)], giving examples such as:

```
Date:   2017-02-21
Combined date and time in UTC:  2017-02-21T10:26:42+00:00
                                2017-02-21T10:26:42Z
                                20170221T102642Z
```

The one thing to be clear: your examples go without any *time zone* information; so they should be assumed to be "local time".

Answer (score 3):

In this String, **T** is just Time component in a standard ISO 8601 date time string represented as `<date>T<time>`. Wikipedia has a [detailed page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations) about this standard format.

In java, you can do this to use it

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
```

I have used `GMT` here just for example. You can set the time zone according to your need. To get more information about `TimeZone` here is the docs [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html)

Comment: Just for the record: the "Z" implies UTC (well, actually no time zone); and yes, GMT is somehow UTC, but I think for being really precise, you should use "UTC" in your example.

Comment: i wrote GMT because i once read "GMT is a time zone and UTC is a time standard", thus i thought when i try to getTimeZone(), i mention Time Zone. ^_^ @GhostCat

Comment: I agree, this isn't really clear. Maybe the better solution would be to mention that terminology part in your answer.

Comment: Good answer except there is no reason to be using `SimpleDateFormat`. That class is now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

Answer (score 2):

ISO-8601 
A single point in time can be represented by concatenating a complete date expression, the letter T as a delimiter, and a valid time expression. For example, "2007-04-05T14:30".

Answer (score 2):

The format of such date is a local date time of [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), without the time-zone.<sup>1</sup> According to Wikipedia, date and time expressed according to ISO 8601 are:

> ```
> Date:                           2017-02-21
>
> Combined date and time in UTC:  2017-02-21T12:34:46+00:00
>                                 2017-02-21T12:34:46Z
>                                 20170221T123446Z
> ...
> ```

There're several ways to create strings with such format in Java. In Java 8, the easiest way is to use the built-in parsing pattern of `LocalDateTime`. The reason why I don't use `ZonedDateTime` is that the time-zone of this date is unknown.

```
// str -> date
LocalDateTime d = LocalDateTime.parse("2009-06-15T13:45:30");

// date -> str
String text = d.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME);
```

<sup>1</sup> [ISO 8601: Time zone designators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators)

Comment: Correction: A "local" date-time value without an offset *is* defined and allowed by the [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard.

Comment: Thank you for reviewing my answer, @BasilBourque. Answer is now updated :)